# c# generated code refers to assembly removed from project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I am getting the following message when compiling my project.

The environment is Visual Studio Pro 2017. .Net Framework 4.6

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required 
to service this request. Please review the following specific error details 
and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'NAME' does not 
exist in the namespace 'FILE' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 27:     using One.Assembly;
Line 28:     using Two.Assembly;
Line 29:     using NAME.FILE;

Source File: C:\LocalDisk\tempFile.cs  Line: 29
```

It is generating a temporary file which refers to an assembly 'NAME.FILE' that has been removed from the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a reference to the file in a web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

let me describe the scenario, AAA.dll depends on BBB.dll and BBB.dll depends on CCC.dll, you have BBB.dll, but you need to add a refrence to CCC.dll as well, while AAA.dll dose not require direct reference to CCC.dll, but you still need it.